# How do I find a key word in a key word in a users input (python 3.4.1)

Tags: python, input, find, key, python-3.4

I want to be able to find a key word in what a users has inputed. For example:

```
key_words = ["screen", "power", "wifi"]

user_input = input("Type: ")

if user_input in key_words:

         print ("yes")

else:

         print ("no")
```

it should output:

```
Type: My screen doesn't work

yes
```

or

```
Type: Hello There

no
```

I have been doing loads of research and cant find a way of doing this in my version of python. If anyone could help, I'd be really greatfull thanks :)

Comment: You have to split `user_input` before checking if any of it is in `key_words`. Your code tests if the whole input string is in `key_words`.

Comment: Do you want to print each message for each keywords or only 1 yes or no if there is a match ?

Answer (score 0):

```
key_words = ["screen", "power", "wifi"]
user_input = input("Type: ")
for word in key_words:
     message = 'Yes' if word in user_input else 'No'
     print(message)
```

If you want to print until a word is found, use this for

```
for word in key_words:
     if word in user_input:
          print('Yes')
          break
     print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is instead of saying `user_input = input("Type: ")`  rather do:`user_input = input(str("Type: "))`
that way python will know that all your input is to be converted into a string before being stored in the variable"input", therefore python will not suspect that your input are all variables but rather strings! also: `key_words = list("screen", "power", "wifi")` works better for me.

`key_words = list("screen", "power", "wifi")`

`user_input = input(str("Type: "))`

`if user_input in key_words`:

```
     print ("yes")
```

`else:`

```
     `print ("no")`
```

your welcome! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for i in key_words:
    if i in user_input:
        print "Yes"
    else: print "no"
```

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.x.